# SwiftUI Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type AppData found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for AppData may be missing as an ancestor of this view

Tags: swiftui

I run the code, then get this Error message:
Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type AppData found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for AppData may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
I googled it to get help, but couldn't find any helpful advice..
So I'm asking here with the code (only showing the lines related to the question) :

1. AppData file

```
struct Shortcut {
    var title: String
    var option: String
}

struct ShortcutViewModel: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var shortcut: Shortcut
    
    var title: String {
        return shortcut.title.capitalized
    }
    
    var option: String {
        return shortcut.option
    }
}

class AppData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userData: [ShortcutViewModel]
    
    @Published var showTitle: String {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(showTitle, forKey: "TitleInput")
        }
    }
    
    @Published var showOption: String {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(showOption, forKey: "OptionInput")
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        userData = [
            ShortcutViewModel(shortcut: Shortcut(title: "What for Dinner?", option: "Chinese")),
            ShortcutViewModel(shortcut: Shortcut(title: "What for Lunch?", option: "Pasta")),
            ShortcutViewModel(shortcut: Shortcut(title: "What for Breakfast?", option: "Toast"))
        ]
        self.showTitle = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "TitleInput")!
        self.showOption = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "OptionInput")!
    }
}
```

2. ContentView file

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTY
    let createpage = CreateView()
    // MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                NavigationBarView()
                NavigationView{
                    ScrollView{
                        HStack {
                            NavigationLink("+ create a shortcut", destination: CreateView())
                                .font(.title3)
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .padding()
                                .frame(width: 200, height: 60)
                                .background(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10,
                                                 style: .continuous)
                                    .fill(
                                        Color(red:0.2, green: 0.45, blue: 1.0, opacity: 0.3)))
                                    
                            Spacer()
                        } //: HStack - link to create page
                        //.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 120)
                        .padding()
                    } //: ScrollView
                    
                    .navigationTitle("All Shortcuts")
                    
                } //: NavigationView
            
            } //: VStack
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
        } //: ZStack
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top)
    } //: var Body
}



// MARK: - PREVIEW
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(text: .constant(""))
        
    }
}
```

3. CreateView

```
struct CreateView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTY
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var appData: AppData
    @State var titleInput2 = ""
    @State var optionInput2 = ""
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                NavigationView{
                    ScrollView{
                        HStack {
                            TextField("what is the title?", text: $titleInput2)
                                .font(.title2)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding()
                                .frame(width: 320, height: 80)
                                .background(
                                    RoundedRectangle(
                                        cornerRadius: 20,
                                        style: .continuous)
                                        .fill(
                                            Color(red:0.2, green: 0.45, blue: 1.0, opacity: 0.3)))
                                .padding()
                        } //: HStack - Textfield - title
                        .padding()
                        
                        HStack (spacing: 10) {
                            TextField("options", text: $optionInput2)
                                .font(.body)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding()
                                .frame(width: 120, height: 60, alignment: .leading)
                                .background(
                                    RoundedRectangle(
                                        cornerRadius: 10,
                                        style: .continuous)
                                        .fill(
                                            Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, opacity: 0.3)))
                                .padding()
                        } //: HStack - Textfield - option
                        .padding()
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            self.appData.showTitle = titleInput2 // *here I get fatal error msg*
                            self.appData.showOption = optionInput2
                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Save")
                                .padding()
                                .background(
                                    Circle()
                                        .fill(
                                            Color(red: 0.25, green: 0.1, blue: 0.6, opacity: 0.25))
                                        .frame(width: 120, height: 120))
                                
                        }) //: Button - save
                        .padding(.top, 150)
                    } //: Scroll View
                    .navigationTitle("Create a Shortcut")
                }//: Navigation View
            } //: VStack
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
        } //: ZStack
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
    } //: Body
}

struct CreateView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CreateView().environmentObject(AppData())
    }
}
```

4. App file

```
@main  // *here I get Fatal Error msg*
struct WFT_demo2App: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(text: .constant(""))
        }
    }
}
```

So when I run the code, I see fatal error msg in CreateView and the main app file, where I marked above.
I looked up the references but they all use old version of Xcode with app delegates and scene delegates which I don't have in my workspace, and I couldn't really apply them to my case.
I'm so stuck with the UserDefaults...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EnvironmentObjects must be supplied by anscestor views!

```
  @main  
struct WFT_demo2App: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {

            ContentView(text: .constant(""))
             .environmentObject(AppData())            // <<: Here!

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that's what I thought but didn't know how to put it... I have one more quick question since I'm getting a new error now.. Do you see anything wrong with the line 'self.showTitle = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "TitleInput")! ' and the next line in 1. AppData file? Cuz I get  "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error right there..

Comment: @PatrickLee: Yes, I noticed it at first place But answered the Question you asked, here in StackOverFlow we are trying to answer and solve one issue per question, please make new question and explain your issue there, I come to new post to help, but for now I think we are done here.

Comment: Yap right, thank you! I will make a new question:)